# Socket.io Randomchat

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I use: node.js , socket.io 1.37 , express.io

My **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
        }
        form {
            background: #000;
            padding: 3px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        form input {
            border: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 90%;
            margin-right: .5%;
        }
        form button {
            width: 9%;
            background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
            border: none;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #messages li {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function() {
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My **server.js** :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');

});

io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

I want create something like chatrandom
Random people(sockets) are connect in private room (only two sockets can join to one room)

What I need to do this? I have this code, I think it's good to start but I don't know what next.
Can you give some advice, explain ?

Comment: did you find a way to fix your problem ? Please let me know how did you solve the issue I also want to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Before you show you users the chat box, you'll want to let them pick a unique username (and assign an ID) or something like that.

Then you'll pair them  with someone else who has no chat partner(look through a list of all your current chats, let the program choose one that doesn't have two ID's associated with it), and have their interaction saved in some sort of lightweight database (Google "NoSQL for JavaScript", [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) is popular).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I am a newbie... Where should I look into if I want to make a random chat? Is there anyway to achieve this without using DB? I have this code right now:
http://socket.io/demos/chat/